# Git: auto-fixup a commit in a feature branch

Tags: git, rebase

When I am done with a feature, often what I would like is to auto-fixup a commit followed by a force-push to a remote origin before a merge to master.

I end up rebasing on top of master so I can fixup a commit, because I found a tiny thing I want to change and I don't want that change as a separate commit. So I rebase interactively, I fixup the last commit, then I force push. Is there a way to do that in one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to fixup the last commit, you could just amend that commit. After authoring your changes, just issue:

```
$ git commit -a --amend --no-edit
```

You'll still have to force-push, though.

Here's a breakdown of [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) options used above:

```
-a, --all: 
Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and 
deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

--amend: 
Replace the tip of the current branch by creating a new commit.

--no-edit: 
Use the selected commit message without launching an editor. 
For example, `git commit --amend --no-edit` amends a commit without changing 
its commit message.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can save the step of editing the list of commits manually in `rebase -i` using `git commit --fixup <commit>` when making your fixup commit. Then, if `rebase.autoSquash` is set to true, `git rebase -i` will automatically turn the line containing this commit into a `fixup` line right below the commit to fix.

Comment: And if `rebase.autoSquash` configuration is not set, you can use `git rebase --autosquash -i` instead. See https://thoughtbot.com/blog/autosquashing-git-commits.

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit -a --amend --no-edit && git push -f
```